# Inter-relation between the four brahmaviharas?

Tags: reference-request, brahmavihara

I read once, online, someone (perhaps in the Tibetan tradition if that matters) saying that the four brahmaviharas are inter-related -- in particular, that too much of one is counteracted by a bit of another.

For example:

- Feeling too sorry for someone (too much compassion/*karuna*) is counteracted by a bit of *mudita* (remembering the ways in which that person is virtuous or fortunate)
- Similarly, too much of each of the other three is counter-balanced by a bit of each of the others

I was reminded of it by [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/24551/254) ("in good there is seed of bad").

I don't remember the explanation I read, though, and I wasn't able to find the reference again.

Is that anything you've heard before? If you know the explanation but don't know a reference for it, that's OK too (I'd be happy to read just your explanation of it even without a reference).

Answer (score 2):

Uppekkha is what is used to straighten Karuna. Not Muditha. Compassion can easily turn into sadness. When that happens you view the situation in terms of Karma and Vipaka: “All beings are the owners of their karma; their happiness and unhappiness depends upon their actions, not on my wishes for them.”

Metta(kindness) can turn into lust when practiced towards attractive women. Then you can use a mental technique like thinking of them as mothers, sisters, daughters or you can meditate on the repulsiveness of the body.

Answer (score 2):

In the essay "[The Four Sublime States](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nyanaponika/wheel006.html)" by Ven. Nyanaponika Thera, there is a chapter entitled "[The Inter-relations of the Four Sublime States](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nyanaponika/wheel006.html#inter)".

I quote a part of it below:

The translation used here: Love = metta, compassion = karuna, equanimity = upekkha, sympathetic joy = mudita. I would have preferred to translate mudita as "empathetic joy" rather than "sympathetic joy".

> Unbounded love guards compassion against turning into partiality,
>   prevents it from making discriminations by selecting and excluding and
>   thus protects it from falling into partiality or aversion against the
>   excluded side.
>
> Love imparts to equanimity its selflessness, its boundless nature and
>   even its fervor. For fervor, too, transformed and controlled, is part
>   of perfect equanimity, strengthening its power of keen penetration and
>   wise restraint.
>
> Compassion prevents love and sympathetic joy from forgetting that,
>   while both are enjoying or giving temporary and limited happiness,
>   there still exist at that time most dreadful states of suffering in
>   the world. It reminds them that their happiness coexists with
>   measureless misery, perhaps at the next doorstep. It is a reminder to
>   love and sympathetic joy that there is more suffering in the world
>   than they are able to mitigate; that, after the effect of such
>   mitigation has vanished, sorrow and pain are sure to arise anew until
>   suffering is uprooted entirely at the attainment of Nibbana.
>   Compassion does not allow that love and sympathetic joy shut
>   themselves up against the wide world by confining themselves to a
>   narrow sector of it. Compassion prevents love and sympathetic joy from
>   turning into states of self-satisfied complacency within a
>   jealously-guarded petty happiness. Compassion stirs and urges love to
>   widen its sphere; it stirs and urges sympathetic joy to search for
>   fresh nourishment. Thus it helps both of them to grow into truly
>   boundless states (appamañña).
>
> Compassion guards equanimity from falling into a cold indifference,
>   and keeps it from indolent or selfish isolation. Until equanimity has
>   reached perfection, compassion urges it to enter again and again the
>   battle of the world, in order to be able to stand the test, by
>   hardening and strengthening itself.
>
> Sympathetic joy holds compassion back from becoming overwhelmed by the
>   sight of the world's suffering, from being absorbed by it to the
>   exclusion of everything else. Sympathetic joy relieves the tension of
>   mind, soothes the painful burning of the compassionate heart. It keeps
>   compassion away from melancholic brooding without purpose, from a
>   futile sentimentality that merely weakens and consumes the strength of
>   mind and heart. Sympathetic joy develops compassion into active
>   sympathy.
>
> Sympathetic joy gives to equanimity the mild serenity that softens its
>   stern appearance. It is the divine smile on the face of the
>   Enlightened One, a smile that persists in spite of his deep knowledge
>   of the world's suffering, a smile that gives solace and hope,
>   fearlessness and confidence: "Wide open are the doors to deliverance,"
>   thus it speaks.
>
> Equanimity rooted in insight is the guiding and restraining power for
>   the other three sublime states. It points out to them the direction
>   they have to take, and sees to it that this direction is followed.
>   Equanimity guards love and compassion from being dissipated in vain
>   quests and from going astray in the labyrinths of uncontrolled
>   emotion. Equanimity, being a vigilant self-control for the sake of the
>   final goal, does not allow sympathetic joy to rest content with humble
>   results, forgetting the real aims we have to strive for.
>
> Equanimity, which means "even-mindedness," gives to love an even,
>   unchanging firmness and loyalty. It endows it with the great virtue of
>   patience. Equanimity furnishes compassion with an even, unwavering
>   courage and fearlessness, enabling it to face the awesome abyss of
>   misery and despair which confront boundless compassion again and
>   again. To the active side of compassion, equanimity is the calm and
>   firm hand led by wisdom — indispensable to those who want to practice
>   the difficult art of helping others. And here again equanimity means
>   patience, the patient devotion to the work of compassion.
>
> In these and other ways equanimity may be said to be the crown and
>   culmination of the other three sublime states. The first three, if
>   unconnected with equanimity and insight, may dwindle away due to the
>   lack of a stabilizing factor. Isolated virtues, if unsupported by
>   other qualities which give them either the needed firmness or pliancy,
>   often deteriorate into their own characteristic defects. For instance,
>   loving-kindness, without energy and insight, may easily decline to a
>   mere sentimental goodness of weak and unreliable nature. Moreover,
>   such isolated virtues may often carry us in a direction contrary to
>   our original aims and contrary to the welfare of others, too. It is
>   the firm and balanced character of a person that knits isolated
>   virtues into an organic and harmonious whole, within which the single
>   qualities exhibit their best manifestations and avoid the pitfalls of
>   their respective weaknesses. And this is the very function of
>   equanimity, the way it contributes to an ideal relationship between
>   all four sublime states.